# How to add additional information to hyperlink?

Tags: html

it is probably a dummy question, but... I generate HTML document from a database. Some parts are generated as hyperlinks, which should contain additional information: Table name, ID of table row etc... 
When user click on it, the program should extract and decode this information and generate another part of database as HTML document.

I can not figure out what is the best way to do it...

can anybody help?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is the querystring.  Take a look at Google, usually its http://www.google.co.uk but after you've done a search the URL is http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mysearchterm Can you see that mysearchterm has been added to the link?

Give this a try, the hyperlink has actually sent "mysearchterm" to Google via the querystring.  You can pass more than one variable like this by separating with an &.  So you would pass the Table name, ID of table row in the link like this.

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to get you started, but be aware that anyone can edit these values so don't pass anything secure.

Comment: thank you very much for navigating me in right direction. I made my research myself based on your recommendation, so I can confirm, that this is a common practice, furthermore it is supported by .net framework... I send special thanks @krike, @Harold

Answer (score 1):

You should add a new attributes.

```
<a href="#" name='link' database='name of db' table_name= "test_table">TEst</a>
```

Comment: I don't believe these are actual anchor attributes + how would they be retrieved?

Comment: If the data has to be encoded in the markup itself, going with the new HTML5 data attributes is the far better approach, IMO: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

But I doubt that's what the author was looking for.

Comment: to retrieve -an attributes you should use java script.(jquery)

Comment: The user specifies he'll be using the information to get the data from a database, javascript cannot do this

Comment: you should not forget that html5 is not supported by all browsers yet. And will mostly not be supported the same way

Comment: +1 This is actually a good answer, and a technique used frequently. jQuery is very good at retrieving this data and even identifying elements based on it. I would recommend using the following format: data-attributeName="attributeVaue" as this will be HTML5 valid when it is supported. It will still work in earlier browsers, just not pass html validation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand but the best way to transfer data across web pages is by using a form and transfering it as a $_GET[''] or $_POST[''] in PHP. Other than that if the hyperlink is just containing some variables you can make it http://www.something.com/getnewdatabase.php?Var1=Database1&Var2=TableRowID then on the other side pick them up with PHP as $_GET[''] variables. I can't think of a way to do it with purely HTML though, hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is with a querystrings

you would have to construct a link something like:

```
http://mysite.com/generate.php?table="name"&id=5
```

You link them to your page that generates the html pages and there you would then be able to get those values, store it in a variable and the run a new query and generate a new html page.

```
$table = $_GET['table'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
```